# Application of Gershgorin theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The Gershgorin theorem says that all eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ lie within the union of discs $D(a_{ii},R_i)$, where $R_i=\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|$.

Furthermore, in the Wikipedia's article on [Gershgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) it is said that the estimation on the radii can be improved if we consider $R_i=\min\{\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|,\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ji}|\}$ (see Section Example).

Now consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0.05&1&1&1\\0.9&0&0&0\\0&0.9&0&0\\0&0&0.9&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now it seems that the eigenvalues should be within $D(0.05,0.9)\cup D(0,0.9)$, but we have $\rho(A)=1.3893$. What's wrong? Does it imply that we cannot tighten the radii as described above?

Comment: In the example the two improved disks are disjoint from the rest (and from each other). That's the point here.

Answer (score 0):

You have miscalculated the disks. The 4 disks are $D(.05,.9)$, $D(0, 1.9)$, $D(0, 1.9)$, and $D(0, 1)$. You forgot that the radius of the disk centered around zero (the second diagonal) is $1+1.9$. Clearly $1.3893\in D(0, 1.9)$.